# What is the function of sudo?

Tags: package, libraries, sudo

I'm just starting to learn code (python) and so learning how to use the terminal...
Often I've got permission errors when I try to install packages and libraries. Each time I can solve it by using 'sudo' but I don't really understand what sudo does that pip does not. 
Can someone help me to understand please? Is there something wrong in my configuration or system? I get that I don't have the permission to install package I need but I don't know why.

Comment: [Linux 101: Introduction to sudo](https://www.linux.com/learn/linux-101-introduction-sudo) - try 'what is linux sudo' in your favorite search engine.

Comment: type this: man sudo

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a little bit ore clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**sudo** allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy." ([sudo manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html))

There are some directories you need administrator privileges to have read/write access. When executing **pip** with **sudo**, the installer will have the permission needed to install some packages. Probably there's nothing wrong with your system or configuration! ^^

Comment: If I understand well, using sudo is not really risky ? Thank you !!

Comment: Well, it's not necessarely a risk, but it can be sometimes. With sudo you could allow a malefic script execute improper commands, or you could change or delete a system's file... Possibilities are many. But in general cases, like installing a new software or a package or updating something, the use of **sudo** is necessary. Just be aware of what you are installing and of where it comes from.

Comment: Thanks again nmschumacher for your help! I'll try to be carefful with the use of sudo!